# Axis equal in C# chart (How to make equal axes in C# Chart control)

Tags: c#, winforms, mschart

I need matlab equivalent of axis equal in C# Chart.
Just like in this question: [Make the X and Y axis scales equal on an Excel chart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1723059/make-the-x-and-y-axis-scales-equal-on-an-excel-chart) but for C# Chart control.
Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using MsChart, you can try to create your own chart using:

`g.DrawLine` where `g` is a `Graphics` object.
You can use a `PictureBox` and declare:

```
Graphics g = pictureBox1.CreateGraphics();
```

In this way, you can simply create your Oxy system and put the point of your data as you wish. 
For instance, if the vertical axis is 500 pixel long and the horizontal one is 1000 pixel long, you can use a 2-fold factor in order to have your axis equal.